# Visual Studio Git details

Tags: git, visual-studio

This is strange , But i cannot see master/branch details at the bottom of visual studio application.

[the marked one is not available in my vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiUZC.png)

Can anyone help me here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Git for Windows and the Visual Studio plugin?  Depending on your version it may not be configured automatically.  You may also need to specify the project you are working on in the team explorer window.

You can download Git for Windows from this site.

https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: I have git installed and the plugins also. im currently working on Visual studio 2015 professional. But still im facing the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but you may need to initialize a repository in the root of your solution.  To do this, you have two options.  1: you can right-click the solution in the solution explorer, and then select add to source control.  Select git as you VCS type. 2: You can navigate to the folder using command prompt.  Once you are in the same folder as your solution use the following commands.  1. git init  2. git add * 3. git commit.  It will the ask you for a commit message.  Enter something like git commit.

Comment: If you are trying to bring down an existing repo, please ensure that you are cloning, and not just downloading the source.  Downloading the source will not give you the repo metadata.  You can clone from the team explorer in Visual Studio, or by using the git clone <repoUrl> in the command line.  When using the command line, ensure that you run the command from the directory you want the code to live in.

Comment: In short, if your not seeing the branch details it has to be for one of the following reasons. 1. You are not in a project with a git repo. 2. You are missing a Visual Studio plugin.  3. You are missing git for Windows.  Happy Hunting.